# How to deploy atg CommerceReferenceStore again after deploying my own atg module?

Tags: java, atg, oracle-commerce

Initially I have installed ATG and CommerceReferenceStore and configured it using ATG CIM. Later on I started working on my own ATG Module by deploying it on "ATGProduction.ear". Now I want to hit the CommerceReferenceStore's default application but I am not to do so! And if I do so it gives an error saying 404-not found!

Now my query is that whether I have to re-install it in order to access it or is there any other way through which I can access it directly with re-installing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it.

Open `%DYNAME_HOME%/../CIM/log/cim.log`

Search for `atg.cim.productconfig.appassembly.RunAssemblerExecutorTask  runAssembler -server`

This will take you to the line where CIM executed runAssembler to generate ATGProduction.ear; The command will be something like this... `runAssembler -server "ATGProduction"  "A:/home/../home/cimEars/ATGProduction.ear"  -m DCS-UI.Versioned BIZUI PubPortlet DafEar.Admin ContentMgmt.Versioned DCS-UI.SiteAdmin.Versioned SiteAdmin.Versioned DCS.Versioned DCS-UI Store.EStore.Versioned Store.Storefront ContentMgmt.Endeca.Index.Versioned DCS.Endeca.Index.Versioned Store.Endeca.Index.Versioned DCS.Endeca.Index.SKUIndexing Store.EStore.International.Versioned Store.Endeca.International`

All you have to do is add your own ATG module at the end of the command, assuming your module is `VarunModule` The new command will be like this

`runAssembler -server "ATGProduction"  "A:/home/../home/cimEars/ATGProduction.ear"  -m DCS-UI.Versioned BIZUI PubPortlet DafEar.Admin ContentMgmt.Versioned DCS-UI.SiteAdmin.Versioned SiteAdmin.Versioned DCS.Versioned DCS-UI Store.EStore.Versioned Store.Storefront ContentMgmt.Endeca.Index.Versioned DCS.Endeca.Index.Versioned Store.Endeca.Index.Versioned DCS.Endeca.Index.SKUIndexing Store.EStore.International.Versioned Store.Endeca.International VarunModule`

Execute this command this will generate a single ear file that contains both CommerceReferenceStore aas well as your own module. Deploy this new ear file in production server instance in your application server and start it, remove any existing deployments on that server to avoid any errors with using same context root etc., best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I don't understand the Endeca part.....the reason being could be that I'm not using Endeca...and I'm using 10.x version

Comment: In which case you should call `runAssembler` with only the modules that you are using. As you can see from above, you should get the `runAssembler` command from your `cim.log`.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said...
But I tell you my runAssembler script that I am using to deploy my module (say VarunModule), "runAssembler -server ATGProduction D:\Shared\E2E\Softwares\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\ATGProduction\deploy\ATGProduction.ear -m  DafEar.Admin VarunModule"

Comment: Here is what you are doing wrong. If you are executing runAssembler with only DafEar.Admin & VarunModule, `you won't be able to access CRS`. I just gave you an example of what is there in machine, So, Don't follow my command exactly, find what is there in your cim.log and append VarunModule.